# SQL Server Previous Day Backup Failure Report from msdb

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was wondering if there was a simple query out there for msdb to get a report of all backup failures (missing backups, backups not completed, etc) from the previous day for multiple databases on a server. I havent been able to find anything like what I need from googling it or on other forums so any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: This may not be a programming question, might be more suitable for serverfault. I'd say that whatever program is responsible for making your backups should also keep a log or report of any failures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no a way to find the failed back ups. there is a table called  `backupset` but only holds the successful backups not the failed ones. You can set up a job to do the back ups for you and send notification on failure. other way would be to relay on the sql server errro log for the failed back ups. Below is a  query that list successful back ups more friendly way.

```
 -- Most Recent Backups and # of days since ANY type of backup.

SELECT  B.name as Database_Name, ISNULL(STR(ABS(DATEDIFF(day, GetDate(),MAX(backup_finish_date)))), 'NEVER') as DaysSinceLastBackup,
ISNULL(Convert(char(19), MAX(backup_finish_date), 100), 'NEVER') as LastBackupDate, 
case 
    when type='D' then '** FULL **' 
    when type='I' then 'DIFFERENTIAL'
    when type='L' then 'LOG'
end as Backup_Type,
case 
    when status > 16 then 'Check DB Status' -- Alert that DB might be ReadOnly, Offline etc...
        else ' '
end as 'DB Status'
FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases B LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.backupset A ON A.database_name = B.name --AND A.type = 'D' 
where B.name not like '%skip these%' 
GROUP BY B.name , a.type, status
ORDER BY B.name , LastBackupDate desc,a.type, status`
```

Comment: ok thats what i thought, since the backups are always conventionally named with the date, i could probably reverse engineer it to find backups where that date doesnt exist, thanks!

Comment: Yup that should work. good luck.